# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat for 64-bit Python 3.4.3 on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, python-3.x

I have ran into this problem trying to install several different python packages, and I can no longer work around this with alternate packages. I read through the other solutions, but none seem to be specific to my particular Python version and operating system.

I am running Python 3.4.3 64 bit on Windows 8.1 laptop.  While install packages such as esutil and fitsio, I get the error: `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`.  This indicates it can't find Visual Studio 2010 C++ compiler.  However I know Visual Studio Express does not have a 64 bit C++ compiler, so that solution does not work.  With Visual Studio Express installed I then get `ValueError: ['path']`

Also, since this is a Windows 8 laptop I can't download the additional Visual Studio SDK 7.1 which is also suggested to alleviate the problem.  What Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 software can I download for Windows 8 in order get a 64 bit C++ compiler?

Alternatively is there a work around using a different C++ compiler, such as mingw32.  I tried mingw32 from a Cygwin installation, but that also fails, so I suspect I need a 64-bit mingw c++ compiler as well.

Comment: The [Windows SDK 7.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) can be a tedious install. There may be snags such as [KB2717426](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2717426); having to first uninstall .NET 4.5 and reinstall it after installing the SDK; and restoring x64 compilers per [KB2519277](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2519277) . See [this vcblog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/31/10148110.aspx) for the recommended install order.

Comment: [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net) is a common choice for building Python C extensions on Windows. It's using the Windows CRT, msvcrt.dll, instead of msvcr100.dll. The two CRTs won't have the same low-level file descriptors, among other issues that rarely seem to be a problem for Python extension modules. You could also try using [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs-2015-product-editions).